# Return all data by specific userID sorted by newest date in Fauna DB

Tags: faunadb

I'm trying to make a Fauna query which will retrieve **all** data from specific user sorted by newest created.

In their documentation (https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/indexes/sort#multiple) there are steps how to do it with multiple data, which you must specify in Values, since there are a lot of fields in collection and sometimes I don't know their name  I want result like this

```
"data": [
    {
      "ref": Ref(Collection("Planets"), "267081152090604051"),
      "ts": 1590967285200000,
      "data": {
        "name": "Jupiter",
        "type": "GAS",
        "userID": "12344",
        "created": "1639665397555"
      }
    },
    {
      "ref": Ref(Collection("Planets"), "267081181884842515"),
      "ts": 1590967313610000,
      "data": {
        "name": "Saturn",
        "type": "GAS",
        "userID": "12344",
        "created": "1639665397446"

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So is it possible to make query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM plantes WHERE userID="12233" ORDER BY created ASC
```

Without specifying which fields to retrieve I want them all no matter the name just filtered by UserID and sorted.

This was the index I created:

```
   CreateIndex({
      name: "get_user_planets_3",
      source: Collection("planets"),
       terms: [
        {
          field: ["data", "userID"]
        }
      ],
      values: [
        { field: ["data", "created"], reverse: true },
        { field: ["data", "name"] },
        { field: ["data", "type"] },
      ]
    })
```

But I don't want to specify the field name I want them all no matter the name just sorted by date.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve all of the data for the selected Set, return the `ref` field in the Index `values` and then `Map` and `Get` the document.

With an Index like this:

```js
CraeteIndex({
  name: "get_user_planets_3",
      source: Collection("planets"),
       terms: [
        {
          field: ["data", "userID"]
        }
      ],
      values: [
        { field: ["data", "created"], reverse: true },
        { field: ["ref"] } // <-- use this to retrieve the whole Document
      ]
})
```

You can retrieve all of the Document's data with a request like this:

```js
Map(
  Paginate(Match(Index("get_user_planets_3"), "12233")),
  Lambda(
    // each Index value is passed to the mapping function
    ["created", "ref"],
    Get(Var("ref"))
  )
)
```

Note that this costs at least 1 Read Operation per Document, due to the `Get` call.  If you want to save on Read costs, then you should optimize your queries for which data you need to receive.  There are even ways that you can have multiple indexes on your collection and let the caller choose which ones as appropriate.  It's all a trade-off that needs to be considered for your own application.

Comment: although it's unusual way, comparing to the sql queries, it's doing the job... thank you very much